# How to be allowed entry to the Teacher's Lounge?

Tags: support, chat, moderator-tools, moderators, teachers-lounge

I'm a moderator on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) and requested access a few days ago. The request hasn't been processed yet (although it may have been over the weekend in some timezones).

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you set your chat profile's parent site to SharePoint Stack Exchange? Your chat profile's parent site needs to be a site which you moderate (diamond and all).