# Make it clear what triggered a bump when user follows the link

Tags: feature-request, edits, hyperlinks, bump, last-activity

Currently, when you click the `Active: Today` link following a bump event, you will mostly be shown what event triggered the bump.

I think this works well for new answers and comments. You navigate to the post/comment, and it's highlighted yellow. I think this also does the same thing for an edit to an answer.

What doesn't happen (which I think should) is that when the question is edited, it is highlighted.

After following the link a few times, I worked out why I'd sometimes not get something highlighted (this is particularly tough when the post is long enough to place the "edited by..." box below the fold). To me it seemed like it wasn't working at all, as typically the page would scroll to the most recent update, which obviously wouldn't happen with an edit to a question.

To reduce confusion and make things a bit more consistent, I think whenever bump links are clicked (like the `Active: Today` one), and it was a question edit that caused the bump, the question should be highlighted.

---

It looks like `?lastactivity` is appended to the question URL, which makes it redirect to a comment/answer/answer-edit. Guess this would need to handle edits to questions and new questions, then the URL should be rendered with this appended in the active tab (which it currently isn't for new questions/question edits). It does appear to always be rendered in the `Active: Today` link.

---

Something else I've noticed is that at this time, it says the last activity was Servy, but the answer (and comments on that answer) he posted is now deleted. Should deleted comments/answers possibly be ignored when determining last activity? Guess it's too complicated to make it depend on the viewing user's rights.

---

Another thing seems to be that the `Active:Today` link doesn't show up after the first activity; for example it still isn't visible for this question, despite there being edits and comments (and one deleted answer).

Comment: Maybe it should do the same thing (highlight the question) when following another bump link (like the time display in the Active tab) when it's a completely new question. (The Active:Today one isn't visible and wouldn't apply in this case).

Comment: I didn't even know you could click that :)

Comment: Related confusion: [Reopening attributed to wrong user on front page and question pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132158)

Comment: @TimStone: Good find, looks like that's along the same lines, but related to post status(?) events such as re-open. Not sure how you'd indicate that visually when you get the the question page though, but it should at least have the correct user (if it's not fixed already).

Comment: It's not, unfortunately. There was an instance just the other day where a question was merged, and the merge caused the bump, but there was no immediate way to tell.

Comment: @TimStone: I'd say the case in that question is worse than the issue i've raised as at least in my case the edited by bit in the question is easily visible on the page, whereas in that case it isn't (is it?)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Can you please clear my confusion, in the question you have mentioned that "I think this works well for new answers and comments". Was it a recent change to bump questions on new comments? Because it is not mentioned here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Possibly it doesn't cause a bump (I thought it did, but I see this hasn't been bumped). I'm pretty sure it does highlight new comments though in the link (which is what I was primarily asking about).

Comment: Maybe there should be a full history/log for all events on a question (and its answers).